# programmatically answer to a dialog in gnome?

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, gnome

Is it possible to control another process' dialog from code?

I want to answer a simple yes|no dialog, which is opened by another program from my own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, as this is what UI testing frameworks like [dogtail](http://fedorahosted.org/dogtail/) do.  Giving a look at the [ATK](http://developer.gnome.org/atk/stable/index.html) (Accessibility ToolKit) may give you aditionnal hints. I think this is what dogtail uses. However, the accessibility framework will need to be enabled to use this technique. Here's the [developer's guide for the ATK](http://developer.gnome.org/accessibility-devel-guide/3.0/accessibility-devel-guide.html).

Answer (score 1):

If the dialog is setup so that you can use cancel for no/dismiss and enter for yes/accept. Then you can use XTest (say via libfakekey to make things easier) to send the appropriate key event to that window. If they have accelerators they could also be used.

It's much more of a hack than using the accessibility framework for doing this but might be useful if you don't have accessibility available.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It turned out that I can't use the ATK afterall, since the dialog I try to control, doesn't support it.